# Save data into existing model instance in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a model called ModelA which uses base class Model, not PersistedModel.
ModelA contains an existing Model instance which contains the following document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf34da5265db517d8e366d3"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5cf34da5265db517d8e366d0"),
    "providers" : [ 
        "123456789", 
        "1598763690", 
        "1407850217", 
        "1720082597"
    ],
    "countByType" : {
        "doctors" : 3,
        "laboratories" : 0,
        "hospitals" : 0,
        "imagingCenters" : 0,
        "other" : 2
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing right now is how to save the data into existing model instance.

```
 var modelInstance = new ModelA({userId: user.id, providers: ['111111111','222222222'], countByType: userProviderData.countByType});
           UserProvider.save({validate: false, throws: false },function(err, user) {
             if(err) {

               console.log('Errorsssssss ',err);
             } else {
               console.log(user);
             }
           });
```

Checked the below documentation, but this is creating new instance, instead of saving into existing Model.

https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/v/1.5.1/#model-save-options-callback

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What version of loopback are you using?

Comment: @farid-nouri-neshat : loopback 3

Comment: What is `UserProvider`?

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani my mistake. Actually UserProvider is modelInstance. But i dont know how to save into existing model instance without creating a new instance. please guide me..

Comment: The answer of @FaridNouriNeshat is correct. Also you didn't put `_id` field in your `modelInstance`. You just did `userId`

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani  i am getting one more document now. the problem is that i already have model instance then why creating new one? can you please tell me where to add _id. i didnt get you. sorry

Comment: In line `new ModelA({userId: user.id, providers: ['111111111','222222222'], countByType: userProviderData.countByType});`, I don't see field id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194330/discussion-between-vishnu-and-ebrahim-pasbani).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use something like updateAll:

```
ModelA.updateAll({_id: yourId}, data);
```

Or by using setId and then save:

```
var modelInstance = new ModelA(data);
modelInstance.setId(yourId);
modelInstance.save();
```

The reason why in your example it didn't update the data was that there was no id passed to the model constructor, you should either pass that or use setId.

Comment: i already have document exists in my model. So is there any need to create new one.. how to save data in existing model instance

Comment: can you tell me how to sace model without creating new instance..also how to pass existing model instance id.. setId is for persistedModelnot for base class Model